# What is hexedit.exe and who originally created it?

Tags: windows, odbc, hex-editor

At our company we use an obscure ODBC tool named FlexODBC Driver for DataFlex. Bundled with that software is `hexedit.exe`. What caught my attention is that the file says it was last modified March 19th, 1986. When trying to run it in Windows 10, Windows says it cannot be run on this PC. I tried running it in compatibility mode for Windows 95 to no avail.

So my questions:

1. What is `hexedit.exe`?
2. What does it do?
3. Who created this program?
4. Is it really that old?

I understand it's a hex editor, but I'm not sure what that means or what it could be used for in any context. A quick Google search did not reveal much on the origin of the program.

Note: my goal is not to run or use `hexedit.exe`, just to understand what it is. (Though if someone knows how to make it run I would be curious.)

Comment: It's that old.  I used to use hexedit to update strings in binary files back in the DOS days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In recent times, computers have standardized on a unit of memory, the *byte*, a group of eight *bits* (0 or 1, binary value). Bytes have 256 values, which can be expressed as the numbers 0-255, or as a **hex**adecimal value, using the 16 characters 0-9 and letters A-F, hence the name *hex* editor. To indicate a number is hex, it may be preceded by 0x. The number 01, decimal = 0x01, hex and 255, dec = 0xFF, hex.

A hex editor can directly manipulate each byte in a string, or even on a disk drive. If you can't use the one shipped with the software, there are many free hex editors, such as [MiTeC's HexEdit](https://www.mitec.cz/hex.html) or [numerous alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/mitec-hexedit/).

**N.B.** A hex editor is a *powerful* tool. If you have to ask what it is, you likely should *not* be using it. Better you should read about Terry Pratchett's [hex computer](https://discworld.fandom.com/wiki/Hex).